# monaca.invokeBrowserは使用できない？

Tags: monaca

初めてスマホアプリを作成しているのですが、アプリの中の外部リンクから
外部ブラウザを起動してページを表示させたいです。
チュートリアルには、monaca.invokeBrowserを使うようにと書いてあったのですが、
試した見たところ、うまく動きません。
http://docs.monaca.mobi/2.9/ja/reference/javascript/utility-29/#monaca-invokebrowser-open-an-external-browser
こちらのページには、monaca.invokeBrowserは使わないでInAppBrowserを使うように記述されています。
https://642dad3ff5abc36218998a19ee31a174f322b763.googledrive.com/host/0B-F5PfgMvTC9dmJONEtWY2xCRm8/201412/conversion_from2_9.html#invoke_browser
こちらはうまく動いたのですが、やはり外部ブラウザで表示させたいと思います。
monaca.invokeBrowser以外の方法でもいいのですが、外部リンクから外部ブラウザを起動させて指定したURLを表示させることはできないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

記憶が正しければ以下のコードを実行するとお使いの端末のブラウザで起動できます。

```
window.open('http://example.com', '_system')
```

しかし、アプリに戻るためにはユーザの操作に委ねられる形になるので、場合によってはこの実装は使えないかもしれません。

リフレッシュを行わずに、同時に別ページを処理したいという場合にはやはり`InAppBrowser`などを利用するのが得策かと思われます。